# Cannot acces mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

I executed the following command to change the DB password:

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=('root') WHERE User = 'root';
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Rows matched: 4  Changed: 4  Warnings: 0

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Now I can not access the DB using the password 'root'. I get the following message:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `Terminal`, please, run this:

- Stop MySQL daemon:

  `/etc/init.d/mysql stop`
- Start safely MySQL:

  `sudo /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`
- Then you can start resetting your password:

  `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root@localhost' = PASSWORD('yourNewPassword');`
  `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

**EDIT**:
I run the commands step by step on my own computer. You can follow them, they run successfully:

```
begueradj@begueradj-X71Q:/var/www$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
[sudo] password for begueradj: 
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql stop

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) utility, e.g. stop mysql
mysql stop/waiting
begueradj@begueradj-X71Q:/var/www$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
[2] 6035
begueradj@begueradj-X71Q:/var/www$ 141023 10:11:43 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
141023 10:11:43 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
141023 10:11:43 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql

begueradj@begueradj-X71Q:/var/www$ mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use mysql;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("begueradj") where User='root';
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 4  Changed: 4  Warnings: 0

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

You can exit now.
BEGUERADJ.

Comment: Catch-22: If he can't enter the password for `root`, he can't use `mysql -u root`.

Comment: @Begueradj It gets stuck like this
'141023 13:48:26 mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
141023 13:48:26 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql'

Comment: @bio-terror see my new edit, and do not forget to use SUDO when you strt MySQL engine safely

Comment: @bio-terror If you want me, I will copy/past all what I did (I tested that on my own computer). For the error you got before, you just have to press ENTER, in fact

Comment: @bio-terror I edited my answer with all the successful commands required to fulfill your goal step by step.

Comment: As I said it worked already with the first solution you posted.